# Раньше было больше?

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, раньше-было-лучше, аналитика-сайта

1. [200 вопросов в день!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5030/15479) (1 апреля 2017).
2. [250 вопросов в день!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7399/15479) (30 мая 2018).

[Теперь же меньше 200](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же посмотреть аналитику, то число вопросов/ответов примерно с начала весны 2018 стало падать.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впрочем, как и число голосов.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть повод беспокоиться?

Можно было бы предположить, что с наполнение "базы знаний" количество новых вопросов будет падать, так как на многие базовые вопросы уже даны ответы. Но тогда бы и на SOen был бы такой тренд.

Я спросил людей с SOen, у них такого тренда не обнаружено, если верить аналитике.

Answer (score 11):

### Ru.SO

При такой настройке графиков сложно оценить детали. Вот [графики за всё время существования RuSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics):

[image: RuSO stats]

Количество ответов перестало расти уже к 2017 году, в 2018 году — поползло вниз. Количество вопросов держалось дольше, но уверенно поползло вниз в 2019 году. Меньше 1000 ответов в неделю — это значения 2015 года.

Количество голосов начало снижаться с 2018 года, в 2019 году резко устремилось вниз. Количество голосов вернулось к изначальной точке в 2000 в неделю.

### En.SO

А вот [статистика на большом SO](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics):

[image: SO stats]

Как можно видеть, графики тоже не самые впечатляющие, однако разница налицо.

Количество ответов незначительно снижается с 2014 года и устремляется к соотношению 1:1 с вопросами. Количество вопросов с 2014 года более-менее стабильно (снижение порядка 5% за пару лет).

Количество голосов не снижается вообще. Оно стабильно с 2015 года.

### Сравнение с En.SO

Теперь сравним по пунктам:

1. Количество вопросов снижается — на большом СО такого почти нет.
2. Количество ответов снижается — на большом СО такое есть, но гораздо мягче.
3. График количества ответов ушёл глубоко вниз под график количества вопросов — на большом СО такого нет (1:2 против 1:1).
4. Количество голосов "за" снижается очень резко — на большом СО такого нет вообще.

### Падение

И в числах относительно лучших времён:

1. Количество ответов упало с 1500 до 1000 в неделю (в 1.5 раза).
2. Количество вопросов упало с 1800 до 1300 в неделю (в 1.4 раза).
3. Количество голосов "за" упало с 4000 до 2000 в неделю (в 2 раза).

По-моему, значения находятся в положении "**всё плохо и будет только хуже**".

### Es.SO

Непохоже, что эта проблема распространяется на остальные локализованные сайты. Например, вот [статистика Es.SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics):

[image: EsSO stats]

Графики более-менее ровные. Есть некоторое падение постов в течение последних нескольких месяцев, но точно оценить сложно. Количество голосов вовсе растёт.

### Pt.SO

[image: PtSO stats]

Тут всё не очень радужно, хотя и не в такой тяжёлой форме, как на Ru.SO. График количества ответов уполз под график количества вопросов, но соотношение 2:3, а не 1:2. График количества вопросов более-менее ровный. Также примечательно отсутствие плато — после роста сразу наступило падение.

Количество голосов упало один раз ступенькообразно, потом держалось ровно, за последние полгода началось медленное падение. Самое интересное — колоссальный рост голосов "против" при падении принятых вопросов — у всех остальных эта статистика практически не меняется со временем, а тут голоса "против" стремительно приближаются к голосам "за" ("протестное голосование"?).

Comment: "Количество вопросов снижается — на большом СО такого нет." - да прямо из графиков видно, что есть. за два года упало с 7.4k до 6.9k.

Comment: Есть явное падение с начала весны (март 2018) у нас, и с конца 2017/начала 2018 на enSO (но падает медленее). Кризис формата? Народ уходит в чатики телеграма?

Comment: @PashaPash Хм, глазомер подвёл. Обновил. / Телега за бугром пользуется спросом?

Comment: @PashaPash Самое заметное падение на большом SO — это ответы с весны 2014 года. Я сам в 2014 только начал жёсткий фарм репы, поэтому не знаю, что там изменилось. / Мне тут в соседнем чате подсказывают, что начало падения на RuSO примерно совпадает с датой возникновения #SOпротивления.

Comment: Да, примерно совпадает, вот только падение началось с марта, а "сопротивление" - это ж вроде май? Падение вызвало сопротивление? :)

Comment: Еще точно есть падение у испанцев - 146->123 вопросов в день за тот же период. И явное падение активности на мете у нас начиная с конца 2017. Вобщем, не растет ничего.

Comment: @PashaPash Вот сколько ни смотрю на график, не вижу чёткой границы: то ли март, то ли май, то ли где ещё. / О, точно, ещё же на метах эта страничка есть. Падение на Метах как раз более-менее оправдано: вопросов для обсуждения реально должно становиться меньше, новые фреймворки для написания вопросов каждую неделю не появляются. Хм... Начало падения ответов на SO совпадает с началом всех графиков MSO... Странно это. / Где испанский график посмотреть?

Comment: Испанцы видны по ссылке из вопроса (на май 17) + текущей странице по всем сайтам. Сорри, ссылку не дам, с телефона :(

Comment: Печально выглядит график голосов. Наверное это означает, что читать чужие ответы стали меньше, теряется смысл жизни в этих местах...

Comment: @avp да в жизни в целом особого смысла нету.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это "немного цитата" из фильма Парфенова "Цвет нации". Не смотрели?

Comment: @avp нет. Я в принципе не большой поклонник кино.

Comment: @PashaPash Попытаюсь добыть графики у испанцев и португальцев.

Comment: @Kyubey "Есть некоторое падение постов в течение последних нескольких месяцев, но точно оценить сложно." - что тут сложного? возьмите данные за тот же период, за который вы брали для ruSO и точно так же разделите. Там падение на 11% по количеству вопросов и на 25% по количеству ответов (в 1.32 раза, так серьезнее звучит). По-моему, значения и у них, и у enSO, и у нас находятся в положении "всё плохо и будет только хуже".

Comment: @PashaPash На Ru.SO падение (1) долгое, (2) резкое, (3) по всем параметрам. У остальных выполняется только 1-2 условия. Статистика ни на одном сайте не блещет, похоже, но на Ru.SO она заметно выделяется беспросветностью.

Comment: @Kyubey да, согласен, у португальцев, например, падение не по всем параметрам - количество голосов против не падает, а растет. Не уверен правда, хорошо ли это :)

Comment: Синхронное падение статистики на нескольких сайтах приурочено, вероятно, не к началу #сопротивления (которое тоже является следствием более общей причины), а к смене политики сайта и SJW-закручиванию гаек. Смена подхода руководства является, судя по всему, отображением новых установок.

Comment: А толку в замере снижения голосов, если снижается и число постов? Тогда бы уж долю голосов по отношению к числу постов измерял.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336932/309650

Comment: Интересно было бы посмотреть обновленную статистику. По ruSO вижу рост с сентября 2019 (правда похоже было большое количество некачественных вопросов, судя по количеству минусов), сильный буст с марта по май (до рекордных 645 вопросов в день 13 мая), потом выравнивание. Относительные величины не смотрел, там скорее всего все так же плохо.

Comment: @insolor Пик с марта по май — это не какое-то событие, а непонятная особенность сбора статистики, потому что на большом SO то же самое с теми же датами. Вероятно, что-то связанное с удалением и прочими автоматическими процедурами. В целом из аномального провала 2019-го года выбрались, текущее состояние выглядит стабильным, ощутимого движения ни вверх, ни вниз на глаз не видно ни на одном графике. График ответов стабильно под графиком вопросов, соотношение не особо меняется.

Answer (score 4):

Да, падение очевидно происходит из-за падения интереса к формату. Новичков перехватывают на другие платформы, нет новичков - старички тоже перестают количественно рости.

Я уже высказывался на эту тему, но повторю здесь. Все это от противоречия между заявлениями и действительностью. А именно, на словах заявляется что СО это база знаний, но в действительности базой знаний он не является. Он просто форум заточенный под вопросы/ответы, эта заточка, как раз, и является тормозящим фактором! Когда вопросов/ответов становится не достаточно, когда требуется обсудить и поспорить или ПОСПОРИТЬ, оказывается что СО ничего не может предложить ибо неформат. Формат ВО быстро исчерпывается и становится не интересно. Плюс к этому некоторая обезличенность кого-то напрягает, меня нет.

Что же делать? Одно из двух- умирать либо меняться. Мне был бы интересен мутант из СО, хабра и вики. Только сейчас я не вижу как это может выглядеть компактно и понятно.

Comment: Как другие платформы их перехватывают? В мессенджерах есть профессионалы, готовые в тысячный раз отвечать очередному новичку из бесконечной очереди таких же на один и тот же вопрос? Или там одни новички дают другим ответы, которые исчезнут как слёзы под дождём?

Comment: Да, если бы был бы раздел со статейками как на хабре, то было интересно почитать

Comment: @iluxa1810 Тут еще возможность отойти от обезличенности

Comment: `Да, если бы был бы раздел со статейками как на хабре, то было интересно почитать` если статья отвечает на какой то технический вопрос, то можно клепать вопрос => статья-ответ с каким то особенным тегом :)

Comment: @tym32167. Если страница не расчитана на такое к-во данных то такой "ответ" будет нечитабельным. Невозможно сделать таблицы, и невозможно определить статьи в отдельную группу. Спойлер как бы есть и нету - надо гуглить в мете как делать. Ссылки внутри ответа что б разбить ответ на логические куски - нельзя.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну я и не говорил, что форматирование тут идеальное. Но для того, чтобы просто идею проверить, думаю, сойдет. Есть у меня сомнения по поводу того, как много присутствующих тут людей готовы писать статьи за бесплатно на чужих по сути ресурсах.

Comment: @tym32167 На хабре за статьи что-то платят?

Comment: @nick_n_a да, у них есть пожертвования и раньше ворде платили авторам. Но и тем не менее - мы не хабр и хабром не станем, потому нет смысла сравнивать.

Comment: @nick_n_a [ППА](https://habr.com/ru/ppa/faq/). От 3к рублей за статью.

Comment: @tym32167 пожертвования не взлетели. Никто не донатил.

Comment: Ну насчёт хабра это **сильно** . Я за 15 минут накидаю вам сотню статей как в хабре . вот примеры заголовков : **ААА Путин ворует мой интернет , что делать ??** , **ФСБ перепрограмировали мою бабушку и лопату, до коле мы будем терпеть ?**, **Выбираем хату в Пинчипухе , чтоб быть дауншифтером попивая смузи и катаясь на моно-колесе** , **Дайжет о модных подворотах в ПХП и какая челка  сейчас тренде,  и подходит моему бекспейсу**

Comment: хорошо, убрал про мессенджеры

Answer (score 4):

Может, вопросы меньше начали задавать только из-за того, что информации стало действительно больше? Людям проще находить под свои нужды, почему никто такой вариант не предполагает. Да, технологии двигаются, вопросов должно быть больше, но вот когда только начинаешь заниматься программированием, то будто уже каждый вопрос на начале пути до тебя разжевали по 100 раз и не составляет труда найти нужный ответ.

Comment: Хотелось бы в это верить. Интересно было бы еще посмотреть график входящего трафика из поисковиков и количества отказов.

Comment: @insolor график есть на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics, доступ от 10к репутации

Comment: @PashaPash, мне пишет, что от 25к

Comment: @insolor хм. вобщем нет, траффик не падает.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну просто падает/не падает не дает никакой информации. В контексте данного ответа возможно по трафику/отказам можно было бы оценить улучшается/ухудшается ли среднее качество.