# Как часто на ruSO задают вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, статистика

Интересно было бы увидеть среднее количество вопросов здесь (на ruSO)  по часам, дням недели и дням года.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Я провёл анализ данных и получил вот такие результаты:

---

> **Внимание:**
>
> - время по UTC
> - данные усреднены за всё время (до 30 апреля 2023 года)

---

### По часам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из того, что пик приходится на 12 часов, можно сделать вывод, что большая часть сообщества проживает в Европе.

---

### По дням недели

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо, для большей части сообщества программирование - это работа (т. к. в рабочие дни задаётся больше вопросов).

---

### По дням года

> **Внимание:**
>
> - Данные усреднены за все **целые** года, т. е. 2023 не считается (т. к. он неполный)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что в праздники задают меньше вопросов (что логично).

В день программиста особого снижения не наблюдается.

---

PS: данные были загружены из https://archive.org/details/stackexchange 30-го апреля 2023 года.

PPS: код для получения графиков доступен по адресу https://github.com/wchistow/ruSO-visual.

Comment: Минус не ставил, но в общем-то результаты очень очевидные получились, никаких интересных выводов.

Comment: Почему же - ответ вполне хороший и интересный. 8 Марта круче 1 Мая )) Держите плюс. Добавьте пожалуйста по какому часовому поясу у вас первый график )

Comment: И Новый год не повод не задавать вопросы)

Comment: Еще можно увидеть, что бОльшая часть сообщества в отпуск ходит летом, судя по снижению числа вопросов в летние месяцы. :)

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов вместе со школьниками и студентами, которые любят кидать свои домашние задания :)

Comment: Такое ощущение, что кол-во вопросов по часам (первый график) - не целое. Например, в UTC-полдень задают 10,25 вопросов? Как такое возможно?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ это среднее значение за большой период времени, вполне может быть нецелым (грубо говоря, 3 дня было 10 вопросов в полдень, 1 день - 11, в среднем - 10,25). Возможно тут имеет смысл моду считать, а не среднее арифметическое (хотя трудно сказать, как тут лучше, я тот еще статистик).

Comment: @insolor в среднем по годам согласен. Но всё равно выглядит дико для заголовка "Количество вопросов" (полтора землекопа). Имхо, стоит вынести факт подсчёта усреднённого значение куда-то в начало ответа, чтобы подобные недоразумения не возникали. А ещё кажется, что для циклических активностей лучше бы подошли круговые диаграммы, чтобы не было разрывов типа пнд-вск, 0-23, 1янв-31дек.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, насчёт круговых диаграмм - мои графики не супер точные, я хотел просто показать отношение (когда меньше/больше), а на круговых диаграммах эти отношения будут видны хуже.

Comment: `можно сделать вывод, что большая часть сообщества проживает в Европе.` вот этого не понял. Всегда думал, что вопросы задаются утром или чаще вечером. Пик на 12 по utc не означает, что все в локальный полдень начинают задавать вопросы :)

Comment: @tym32167 про Европу, действительно, не очевидно. Но про публикацию чаще утром/вечером — тоже. Надо иметь статистику по локальному времени вопрошающего. Альтернативно — сравнить аналогично с enSO (но это всё равно вилами по воде будет).

Comment: Не хватает по годам — посмотреть тренд, так сказать, растет ruSO (что вряд ли...) или сдувается...

Comment: @Harry, посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9667/507426.

Comment: Мда, ничего оптимистичного...

Comment: @Harry, в том ответе уже устаревшие данные, после того периода был довольно значительный подъем, а потом опять падение. Из нового неоптимистичного - в апреле прошлого года количество посещений за неделю упало в 1,5-2 раза, а новых посещений - примерно в 4 раза: https://i.stack.imgur.com/for10.png К аналитике основного сайта у меня нет доступа, интересно было бы посмотреть как там.

Comment: @insolor Ну, весна прошлого года вообще не показатель для русскоязычного сайта...

Comment: @Harry если бы было восстановление, то да, не показатель. Но количество посещений в итоге не восстановилось, там график по текущий момент. В феврале-марте там видно падение-восстановление, а после апреля восстановления нет.

Comment: @Harry хотя возможно это какое-то изменение способа подсчета статистики, поэтому неплохо бы статистику основного сайта посмотреть.